# Chrome OS and Synergy?

Tags: synergy

Has anyone found a work-around to getting Synergy to work on Chrome OS? (I mean running in the vanilla, non-developer version).

This is the main reason that is keeping me from getting a license. :(

I found mentions of requests for product features here back in *2014*: 
https://github.com/symless/synergy/issues/3363

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/symless/synergy-core/issues/3363

Comment: Extremely good question.